# Why doesnt my custom font load even though works in local?

Tags: html, css, web, fonts

Im trying to use a Raleway font family for my heading in my website. In local testing it works fine but when pushed to git and run on git pages it doesnt work. I have even specified the text font TTF file in directory but still doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

The website

https://codesniper99.github.io/Portfolio/

**my html index file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- copyright akhil vaid if anybody copies this my code is here so good luck 2017UCO1521 -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body style="color:black"></body>
    <div class="container text-pri" style="font-family:Open-sans; padding: 0%;margin-right: 0%;    ">
     <!-- Header -->
     <div class="parallax">
         <span  class="topbar" > ABOUT</span>
         <span  class="topbar" > &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  SKILLS</span>
         <span  class="topbar" > &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;EXPERIENCE</span>
         <span  class="topbar" > &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;ACHIEVEMENTS</span>
         <span  class="topbar" > &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;CONTACT ME</span>
        <span class="center rcorners2 " style="font-family:Raleway ;font-size: 4.0em;"> 
           <span style="color: #E04343;">A</span><span >KHIL</span> 
           <span style="color: #FFE800;">V</span><span>AID</span> 
        </span>
     </div>  

        <!-- Introduction -->
        <div class="intro rcorners1">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;">ABOUT ME</h3><br>
        <p>
                I'm a second year Under-graduate student currently pursuing Computer Science and Engineering at
                NSIT, New Delhi, India. I'm new to the industry and keen to expand my skill set.<br> <br> I have a curiosity in
                the field of Web Development and Competitive Programming and using it to solve real world
                problems and am willing to take up opportunities to delve into it.
                <br>
                <br>

        </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Skills -->
        <h5><b>
                Skills and Technologies
            </b>
            </h5>
            <ul>
                    <li>C++ (GNU 14.2), C
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            Java
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                           Python 3.1
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            HTML (HTML -5, Canvas)
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            CSS3 (Boot-Strap, Materialize CSS Frameworks)
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            JavaScript (Learning)
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            ExpressJS (Learning)
                    </li><br>
                    <li>
                            Experience with Django Framework
                    </li><br>
                    <li>
                            Knowledge of Git and VCS
                    </li><br>

                </ul>                
                <br>
    <!-- Experience -->
        <h5><b>
            Experience
        </b>
        </h5>
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li>    Currently working as Lead Back-end Developer at ICTS (IntuiComp TeraScience) under
                        guidance of IIT-Delhi and Dr. Arpan Kar. Developing a Learning Management system for
                        machine learning students and professionals alike to take part in and avail lectures and
                        conduct hackathons globally. Has been successfully launched in Afghanistan, Hong-Kong,
                        France. [<a href="www.icts-learninganalytics.com">www.icts-learninganalytics.com</a>] (2018-present)
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                        Working as Lead-developer for a trading firm in creating proprietary software using MQL4
                        on MT4 and Uniglobe platform(2017-present)
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                        Created RESTful API and website for an Android application focusing on decreasing Smoking
                        Addiction in individuals by positive reinforcement. It used Django framework and we created
                        our own local server.
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                        Made a working Hospital-Management DBMS (Database Management system) for 3rd
                        Semester project. It was created using JDBC in Netbeans IDE.
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                        Made an Android application to maintain attendance for college students. Developed in
                        native android
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                        Came in top 100 teams in SE- Asia region in ACM-ICPC online qualifier round.
                </li>
            </ul>
        </p>

        <!-- Academics -->
        <h5><b>
                Academic Achievements
            </b>
            </h5>
            <ul>
                    <li>Qualified for ACM-ICPC Regionals 2018-19 at IIT Kharagpur and Kanpur
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            Secured AIR- 2412 rank in JEE Mains.
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            Top 10% of College Department (COE)
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            Top 10% in CBSE class 12th result
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            10 CGPA in class 10th
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            Secured and qualified as a JSTSE scholar from State of New Delhi
                    </li>
                </ul>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**my main.css**

```
.intro
{
    background-color: #f5d7f8;
    margin-left: 64px;
    margin-right: 64px;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 64px;
    padding-right: 64px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top:35px;
}
.rcorners1 {
    border-radius: 25px;

    padding: 20px;

  }
  .rcorners2 {
    border-radius: 12px;

    padding: 15px;

  }
  @font-face { font-family: Raleway; src: url('text/Raleway/Raleway-Light.TTF'); }

  @font-face { font-family: Open-sans; src: url('text/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.TTF'); }
.parallax {

    background-image: url("images/laptop.jpg"); opacity: 0.75;
    min-height: 650px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;


  }

  .text-pri{
 background-color:whitesmoke;

  }
  body {    
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.center {
    position: absolute;
    left:30%;
    top: 40%;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.85;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  }
  .topbar{
      color:white;position: relative;
      padding-top: 30px;

      margin-top:30px;
      margin-left:30px;
      font-size: 20px;

  }
```

**my git repo if needed**

https://github.com/codesniper99/Portfolio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Raleway google font`  I have import `Raleway` font into css so you not need to call from anywhere. and use this as `font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;`

Online font using is good for your site.

also use `font-wight` css for making font `bold` `light` as `font-weight:200` , `font-weight:300` , `font-weight:600` same as imported css.

```css
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,100i,200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i');
    .intro
{
    background-color: #f5d7f8;
    margin-left: 64px;
    margin-right: 64px;
    font-size: 23px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 64px;
    padding-right: 64px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    padding-top:35px;
}
.rcorners1 {
    border-radius: 25px;

    padding: 20px;

  }
  .rcorners2 {
    border-radius: 12px;

    padding: 15px;

  }
  /* @font-face { font-family: Raleway; src: url('text/Raleway/Raleway-Light.TTF'); }

  @font-face { font-family: Open-sans; src: url('text/open-sans/OpenSans-Regular.TTF'); } */
.parallax {

    background-image: url("https://codesniper99.github.io/Portfolio/images/laptop.jpg"); opacity: 0.75;
    min-height: 650px; 
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;


  }

  .text-pri{
 background-color:whitesmoke;

  }
  body {    
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.center {
    position: absolute;
    left:30%;
    top: 40%;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.85;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  }
  .topbar{
      color:white;position: relative;
      padding-top: 30px;

      margin-top:30px;
      margin-left:30px;
      font-size: 20px;

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- copyright akhil vaid if anybody copies this my code is here so good luck 2017UCO1521 -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
   
</head>
<body style="color:black"></body>
    <div class="container text-pri" style="font-family:Open-sans; padding: 0%;margin-right: 0%;    ">
     <!-- Header -->
     <div class="parallax">
         <span  class="topbar" > ABOUT</span>
         <span  class="topbar" > &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  SKILLS</span>
         <span  class="topbar" > &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;EXPERIENCE</span>
         <span  class="topbar" > &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;ACHIEVEMENTS</span>
         <span  class="topbar" > &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp;CONTACT ME</span>
        <span class="center rcorners2 " style="font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;font-size: 4.0em;"> 
           <span style="color: #E04343;">A</span><span >KHIL</span> 
           <span style="color: #FFE800;">V</span><span>AID</span> 
        </span>
     </div>  

        <!-- Introduction -->
        <div class="intro rcorners1">
            <h3 style="text-align: center;">ABOUT ME</h3><br>
        <p>
                I'm a second year Under-graduate student currently pursuing Computer Science and Engineering at
                NSIT, New Delhi, India. I'm new to the industry and keen to expand my skill set.<br> <br> I have a curiosity in
                the field of Web Development and Competitive Programming and using it to solve real world
                problems and am willing to take up opportunities to delve into it.
                <br>
                <br>

        </p>
        </div>
        <!-- Skills -->
        <h5><b>
                Skills and Technologies
            </b>
            </h5>
            <ul>
                    <li>C++ (GNU 14.2), C
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            Java
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                           Python 3.1
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            HTML (HTML -5, Canvas)
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            CSS3 (Boot-Strap, Materialize CSS Frameworks)
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            JavaScript (Learning)
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            ExpressJS (Learning)
                    </li><br>
                    <li>
                            Experience with Django Framework
                    </li><br>
                    <li>
                            Knowledge of Git and VCS
                    </li><br>

                </ul>                
                <br>
    <!-- Experience -->
        <h5><b>
            Experience
        </b>
        </h5>
        <p>
            <ul>
                <li>    Currently working as Lead Back-end Developer at ICTS (IntuiComp TeraScience) under
                        guidance of IIT-Delhi and Dr. Arpan Kar. Developing a Learning Management system for
                        machine learning students and professionals alike to take part in and avail lectures and
                        conduct hackathons globally. Has been successfully launched in Afghanistan, Hong-Kong,
                        France. [<a href="www.icts-learninganalytics.com">www.icts-learninganalytics.com</a>] (2018-present)
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                        Working as Lead-developer for a trading firm in creating proprietary software using MQL4
                        on MT4 and Uniglobe platform(2017-present)
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                        Created RESTful API and website for an Android application focusing on decreasing Smoking
                        Addiction in individuals by positive reinforcement. It used Django framework and we created
                        our own local server.
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                        Made a working Hospital-Management DBMS (Database Management system) for 3rd
                        Semester project. It was created using JDBC in Netbeans IDE.
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                        Made an Android application to maintain attendance for college students. Developed in
                        native android
                </li>
                <br>
                <li>
                        Came in top 100 teams in SE- Asia region in ACM-ICPC online qualifier round.
                </li>
            </ul>
        </p>

        <!-- Academics -->
        <h5><b>
                Academic Achievements
            </b>
            </h5>
            <ul>
                    <li>Qualified for ACM-ICPC Regionals 2018-19 at IIT Kharagpur and Kanpur
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            Secured AIR- 2412 rank in JEE Mains.
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            Top 10% of College Department (COE)
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            Top 10% in CBSE class 12th result
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            10 CGPA in class 10th
                    </li>
                    <br>
                    <li>
                            Secured and qualified as a JSTSE scholar from State of New Delhi
                    </li>
                </ul>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks the import worked just fine! Yes I shouldve imported!

Answer (score 0):

Hey root of the your local directory and your github page might be different can you try with relative path starting with `./`

```
src: url('./text/Raleway/Raleway-Light.TTF')
```

Comment: can you try ../ as well